# Can you read and delete chunk of a file?

Tags: c++, linux

I am using ofstream and ifstream to read a chunk from a file post it over middleware (DDS) to another process and the other process writes that chuck of the file.

Basically transferring a file. The two components are unaware of each other and may live on the same hardware or on different hardware (DDS takes care of the transfer either way).

This is all working, however when I try to do this with a large file (>500MB) and if the destination component is on the same board, then I run out of RAM (since 500 x 2 = 1GB which is my limit).

So I am thinking of reading a chunk from a file deleting that chunk of the file and then sending the chunk. So I end up with:

```
A        B
12345 ->
2345  -> 1
345   -> 12
45    -> 123
5     -> 1234
      -> 12345
```

Where each number is a chunk of a file.

I am using linux, so I can use any linux APIs directly, but would probably prefer a pure c++ approach. I can't really see any good options here. i/ostream does not appear to let you do this. Options like `sed` will (I think) end up using more memory by copying.

Are there any better mechanisms for doing this?

### Update

The files are stored in RAM via a `tmpfs` partition

Comment: Dose the order you read the file matter?  If not, you can start at the end of the file and work your way forward in your reader.

Comment: Why do you need to delete chunks from the file? I would read from the file in chunks and then delete the whole thing when you're done. That's what file transfer programs normally do.

Comment: @NathanOliver interesting point.. I need to re-assemble the file at the other end so that it is identical, that would mean inserting chunks at the start of the file... not quite sure how to do that, but definitely an interesting idea. I guess you would use something like `fs::resize_file(filename, nnn);` to truncate the file?

Comment: It's not clear why transferring a large file should require large amounts of RAM.  The typical approach is to read a small amount, transfer that, write it to disk on the receiver, then read the next small amount, transfer that, write that to disk, and so on, until all the data is transferred; that way the amount of RAM required is constant, regardless of how large the file is.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that is what I currently do - this is to free up memory as the file is transferred (~65KB at a time) so I never want to use more RAM the 500MB (for a file of 500MB)

Comment: Freeing up disk space won't lower RAM usage. Disk space and RAM are separate things. What you need to do is (1) Read the file in a chunk at a time, not all at once; and (2) Make sure your middleware doesn't buffer up the entire contents in some internal buffer. Check that it is sending the chunks as you generate them and isn't waiting for the entire file to be read in first.

Comment: @JohnKugelman sorry I might not have been clear the "disc" is tmpfs - i.e. RAM

Comment: if they're on the same machine, then why do you transfer at all?

Comment: @appleapple the file transfer mechanism I am using is "location independent". Files can be transferred from machine to machine or within the same machine - using DDS.  So to do this I would need to have a special case and determine where the destination is - which I can/might do - as it appears there are not many better approaches! :) - so this is a valid point!

Comment: fwiw I believe it's possible to do what you want at least on some filesystem, USN Journal for example.

Comment: and generally, one should be able to modify the filesystem record and remove some chunk, probably easier for leading chunks. (which would change the file size, btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using linux, so I can use any linux APIs directly, but would
> probably prefer a pure c++ approach. I can't really see any good
> options here. i/ostream does not appear to let you do this. Options
> like sed will (I think) end up using more memory by copying.
>
> Are there any better mechanisms for doing this?

There is no standard mechanism in C++ or Linux for shortening a file in-place by deleting data from the beginning or middle.  Most file systems don't work in a way that would support it.  When one wants to delete data from such a position, one has to make a new copy of the file, omitting the data that are to be deleted.

You *can* shorten a file by removing a tail, but that does not serve your purpose unless possibly if you send chunks in reverse order, from tail to head.  However, the most natural ways I can think of to support that in an application such as yours would involve pre-allocating the full-size destination file, and that would have the same problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: thanks for this explanation.... I suppose this means that I don't really want to use "files" for this and that I might be better off using raw memory to store / transfer the file (then I can mess around with free'ing the "file" in chunks or such

Comment: If the records in the file are fixed length, one could place an "in-use" or "available" flag.  Thus, records can be overwritten in the same file without writing to a new file.

Comment: Yes, @ThomasMatthews, I oversimplified when I said "one has to".  If space efficiency is paramount over time efficiency then one can in principle effect a delete in-place by shifting the file contents toward the front of the file to fill in the gap, then truncating the tail.  I've never seen it done in practice, and I suspect that's in part because it's risky: if something goes wrong in the middle of the process then the file ends up corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you read ... chunk of a file?

You can seek to an offset to start reading from anywhere of a file, and you can stop reading once you've read the chunk entirely.

> Can you ... delete chunk of a file?

Operating systems present files with an interface similar to a vector. Deleting a chunk from the end of a file is trivial like it is trivial to erase elements from the end of a vector. You can simply call  `std::filesystem::resize_file` with the new size which is the chunk size subtracted from the original size.

Deleting a chunk from elsewhere is more complex. You must first seek to the beginning of the chunk, then copy the content from after the chunk into the start of the chunk and forward. The complexity of this operation is linear in distance from the start of the chunk to the end of the file. When you have copied all of the trailing content, you can resize to remove the excess.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting... so its sort of possible, but requires copying the end of the file over the top of the start of the ("shifting it backwards") - if I understand correctly. This does sound like it may be quite slow - but would probably get over the memory constraints. Thanks